# Haskell Targeting elements in list of lists

Tags: haskell

Okay, I'm new to Haskell, and need help getting my head around functional approaches to     problems.

I have a list of list. More specifically `[[Char]]`.

I would like to target a specific element in a list, and look at the elements above, below, and to the left and right of the element.

For example:

```
["-------",
 "-------",
 "---N---",
 "--WOE--",
 "---S---",
 "-------",
 "-------"]
```

Where `O` is the element I'm targeting, and `N,S,E,W` are the elements directly surrounding the element `O`.

I'm made a function that gets an `(x,y)` coordinate of the element `O`, and it is as follows:

```
find :: Eq a => [[a]] -> a -> (Int,Int)
find [[]] _ = (-1,-1)
find (x:xs) el = findHelper (x:xs) (0,0,el)

findHelper :: Eq a => [[a]] -> (Int,Int,a) -> (Int,Int)
findHelper [[]] _ = (-1,-1)
findHelper (x:xs) (row,col,el)
    | x == [] = findHelper xs (row+1,0,el)
    | (head x) == el = (row,col)
    | otherwise = findHelper ((tail x) : xs) (row,col + 1,el)
```

This `(x,y)` coordinate system is 0-indexed. I just can't for the life of me figure out once I have the position of the element I'm looking for, how to figure out what elements are surrounding it.

Sorry if this isn't the most clear of questions, and I can elaborate more if I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not always possible, since lists don't have fixed sizes. If you can ensure that however, it is possible to do this, otherwise you will need a lot of checks to prevent problems. I'll show a way you can get the surrounding elements, but you will have to build in some extra checks to make sure it does not try to lookup an element that is out of bounds for example.

This should get you a list with the surrounding elements:

```
findSurrounding :: [[a]] -> (Int, Int) -> [a]
findSurrounding matrix (x,y) = map (getElementAt matrix) positions
    where positions = [(x - 1, y), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1), (x, y + 1)]

getElementAt :: [[a]] -> (Int, Int) -> a
getElementAt matrix (x, y) = (matrix !! y) !! x
```

I have not tested the code so it might need some tweaking, but it should get you started.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Yes, I can guarantee each list has a fixed size, so that's not a problem. Thank you!